# Is there a way to wait for batch process to complete in Mule 4?

Tags: batch-processing, synchronous, mulesoft, mule4

I have a mule flow that runs a batch job. What I have found is that the batch job will branch and my flow will continue on. I would like to wait till the On Complete gets hit and return those results. I found that in older version there was a scope of run-and-wait. I don't see an equivalent in Mule 4. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Batch runs asynchronously with respect to the flow. That was the same in Mule 3. 
I guess you could send a message to a VM queue in the onComplete stage and wait for it to be received on the flow.